# Bake multiple textures into one texture issue

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking, baking

When i bake my textures into one texture,
target texture doesn't bake all faces so there are many black spaces in target texture,

the other textures (original textures) changed too which not what i want.
some of faces baked into target texture and other baked in another original texture

---

Steps:

1. make new UV map keep camera icon on original one and selected new one.
2. Make new Image Texture.
3. Unwrap mesh for new texture.
4. add taget texture to every material and keep it selected
5. bake while selected the mesh (Diffuse bake)

---

why blender change original textures while i selected just target texture ?
do i have problem in steps of baking ?

note: my original UV map scaled up so faces out of border